# Determine that no records have been created for 4 days in table on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

There is a table "pressure" with fields:

```
id - integer
value - integer
created_at - timestamp
```

Is it possible to determine if there was a window of more than 4 days in a row when no records were created. That is, if the period is 4 days in a row, when there were no records. There are a lot of records. But usually a break in the creation of records is no more than 1 - 2 days.

Comment: It's easily possible: find all rows where no other row exists with a timestamp in the four following days.

Comment: Search in StackOverflow for `postgresql gaps and islands`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres permits subtraction of dates/timestamps, the result of which is an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). You then compare that result to the specific interval of interest. The [lag()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function provides access to the prior row thus the previous `created_at` value. So: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/e4W4tK_m))

```
select sq.* 
  from (select p.*
             , lag(p.created_at) over(order by p.created_at) previous_date
             , p.created_at - lag(p.created_at) over(order by p.created_at) days_between
        from pressure p
       ) sq
 where sq.days_between > interval '4 days';
```